# Find GPS point within a set of polygons

Tags: postgresql, gps, polygon, postgis, point

I'm trying to figure out how to determine in which polygon (each polygon is the boundary of a watershed, in my case) a set of GPS coordinates lies.

I am using PostGIS and am very new to it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to OS. Can you add pictures/code to your question? Right now it is impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get you started:

```
select gps.*, watershed.*
from gps
left join watershed on ST_Within(gps.geom, watershed.geom)
```

See more info on [ST_Within](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html). Also check out http://gis.stackexchange.com for related questions/answers.